# PHP script can not format the date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a datepicker that shows the date in the following format: `date('d/m/Y')` the date is represented as: `29/06/2017`.

The date column in my database accepts the format: `Y-m-d`. Witch is represented as: `2017-06-29`.

I am trying to convert the date with the following script:

```
$single_cal4 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($single_cal4));
```

When I execute the PHP script that sends the date to the database the date will not insert. I get the date `1970-01-01` in my database.

Does someone know why this is happening and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does `strtotime($single_cal4)` outputs ?

Comment: Standard format for `/`-separated date is `m/d/Y`

Comment: The output is: `-3600`

Comment: Append an `$single_cal4 = replace("/" ,"-", $single_cal4);` to your line

Comment: Please read [The 3rd NOTE in the manual for `strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) **The manual** is always a good place to START your debugging process

Comment: When I do an `echo $single_cal4;` I get: 1970/01/01

Comment: When `strtotime()` see's a slash seperator it assume American date format. So when it tries to work out Month 29 it gives up and outputs the start of the unix clock which is what you got. Convert the slashes to hyphens and it will assume a Sensible date format and then it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe reason is **$single_cal4**. You make sure that **$single_cal4** is valid date string. In other way you can try this:

```
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $single_cal4);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I get an error with your script

Comment: Can you share error?

Comment: My mistake. It is working. Thanks